# Failing to load Google Maps for iOS with flutter

Tags: ios, google-maps, flutter, dart

I made a page in my app that shows a Google map with plenty of markers. When I run it with my android emulator it runs without any problem, but when I set the same android emulator to operate as an iOS device, (with dart dev) it shows only a white screen.

The Google maps watermark doesn't show up neither do the markers and everything. I have already checked my API key and it's correct. Maybe it's an emulator error. I have tried the same in many android emulators.

Platform : iOS
[image]

Platform: Android
[image]

Would anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should set embedded views preview in **Info.plist**.
Add the key io.flutter.embedded_views_preview and the value YES in **Info.plist** file.

Comment: I have already done that. I have followed all the instructions I could find

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the simulator's location was set to `none`. Setting to `Apple` fixed the white screen.

[image]